# Type Declaration in Styled Component CSS file giving off errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-typescript

I am trying to figure out why TypeScript is throwing an error in the styled  component css file even though the type is obviously an object. Please see my code below:

```
export const OverlayCTA = styled.div<{
  ctaPosition?: object
}>`
  margin: 0.625rem 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.top };
  left: ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.left };
  bottom:  ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.bottom };
  right:  ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.right };
  height: ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.height };
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    margin: 3.375rem 0 0;
  }
```

ctaPosition is a prop containing an object that is passed from the component. As you can see, I declared the type as an object, however, I am getting the following error. Not sure why as it is an object type.

It is saying:
Property 'height' does not exist on type 'object'.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the full details for the `ctaPosition` type because typescript does not know that `height` or the other keys exists in `object`.

you can define it above like

```js
export type CtaPositionType = {
  top: string; //or number whichever it is
  left: string; //or number whichever it is
  bottom: string; //or number whichever it is
  right: string; //or number whichever it is
  height: string; //or number whichever it is
}

export const OverlayCTA = styled.div<{
  ctaPosition?: CtaPositionType
}>`
  margin: 0.625rem 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.top };
  left: ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.left };
  bottom:  ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.bottom };
  right:  ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.right };
  height: ${({ctaPosition}) => ctaPosition.height };
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    margin: 3.375rem 0 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Errors went away. Do you know if it is good practice to keep the type Object like that in the styled component file itself? @unhackit

Comment: If you are defining an object type with values, it is always good to define it's values like we did above. If you are too lazy to do so, you can use `Record<any, any>`, which says it's an object with `any` key and `any` value, and typescript will not shout at you. The only downside is that you will not get type suggestions